# Syntax Errors Testing Static Library in C++

Tags: c++, struct, static-libraries

I have a very simple setup to try to test a staticLibrary:
I get error Syntax error: Identifier MyDataT, which points me to the function declaration in MyLib.h? Any reason why struct isn't recognized in the second solution? 
Here is my pseudo code:

```
//MSGDefs.h ==> header file only contains struct defs like this:
 typedef struct __msg {
    unsigned long dest; 
     unsigned long src; 
  }MsgT

 typedef struct __mydata : public MsgT
 {
   TimeT time;  
   DateT date;  
 }MyDataT;


//======== Library generates staic lib MyLib.lib, this generates library fine=======
//MyLib.h
  #include MSGdefs.h
  class X{
     void process(MyDataT *data);
    }

//MyLib.cpp
  void X::process(MyDataT *data) { // do processing here ...}

//========================================

//MyTestLibProj.cpp  -- Another Solution links to MyLib.lib
 #include MyLib.h  ==> This causes error of identifier MyDataT ???
  int main(){
   //  X x = new X();

  }
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `__mydata` tag after `typedef struct`?

Comment: Why the `typedef`? Why not just `struct MyDataT{}`?

Comment: Did you really use `#include MSGdefs.h`? That should be `#include "MSGdefs.h"`. Similarly, use `#include "MyLib.h"`.

Comment: Are you sure MyTestLibProj.cpp includes correct MyLib.h and MSGdefs.h? Are TimeT and DateT defined?

Comment: "My code has a syntax error. Instead of showing you my code, I will show you sort-of my code. Help me find the error in my code." Reminds me of an insurance commercial.

Comment: Sure, If I comment out lines in the library that take structs, things work fine.

Comment: @user45.., this is a concept question, it is not a syntax error per say.

Comment: Like nsislent22 said, MyDataT is undefined because it uses other types which are undefined.  There are also missing semicolons and you need a pointer to X to hold new X().

Comment: As I mentioned on top, this is pseudo code.. Anyways I found the solution.